# Maven Custom Plugin Descriptor

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm Trying to create a Maven Plugin, but if i use @Mojo annotation i've to create a mojo descriptor  with maven plugin-plugin already when i use java doc without the new maven plugin annotation the descriptor is auto generated  (or maven does not want it)....

1 Case:

```
@Mojo( name = "touch", requiresProject=false, defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.INSTALL)
public class MyMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
     ....
}
```

POM:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-maven-pluginbis</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <name>first-maven-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <type>jar</type>
     <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
 </project>
```

Maven does not work

2 Case:

```
/**
* Echos an object string to the output screen.
* @goal echo
* @requiresProject false
*/
public class EchoMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
   ....
}
```

POM:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>first-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>first-maven-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How can it be?

Comment: why when i use maven plugin annotations i've have to use the maven plugin plugin to generate mojo descriptor, instead when i use javadoc like case 2 i don't need to use maven plugin plugin and maven don't ask me for a mojo descriptor?? Have you understand me?

Comment: No oneeeee can help me???

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to specify the goal of maven-plugin-plugin to generate the descriptor?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```